# Writing to file VB6 without new line?

Tags: vb6, file, newline

I have some strings I want to write to a file in VB6. I can write it fine, but every time I do it adds a new line automatically after each write command.

Is there a function or a way to just write to the file without the automatic new line?

Comment: Can you show some code how you write the strings right now?

Answer (score 11):

The advice to use the semicolon is correct, but you most likely don't want to use it in conjunction with `Write #`, which will enclose your output in quotation marks. Use `Print #` instead.

```
Print #handle, "Hello";
Print #handle, " world";
```

Comment: In addition to quotations marks, the Write statement adds commas when you use a semicolon in the output list.  See my comment on Alex's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543883/writing-to-file-vb6-without-new-line/2544022#2544022

Answer (score 1):

You can use a semicolon after the Write command, for example:

```
Write #handle, "Hello";
Write #handle, "world";
```

Comment: The output of this is `"Hello","world",`, which may not be desirable.

Comment: Or on the other hand, it might - if you want to output a CSV for example. The OP says "it adds a new line automatically after each write command" so I assume that's what he was using in the first place.